# Why Android Studio emulator is extremely slow?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm using Android Studio version 3.2 and I have 12GB ram and double graphic cards(NVIDIA and INTEL).

I already installed **HAXM** and also forces **emulator.exe** and **qemu-system-x86_64.exe** to work with NVIDIA.

But still the emulator is extremely slow

Comment: What exactly emulator have you used? My Nexus 5X API 24 Emulator works well but Nexus 5X API 27 and above are very slow, I check memory and CPU costs in **Android Profiler** it shows much higher than others, even simulators have the same density.

Comment: Yes working with Nexus 5X API 24 is much faster, thank you. You can post this as an answer to be accepted.

Comment: okay @Ayoub I did it.

Comment: OMG 16 GB of ram and still slow. I have 8GB ram in my HP laptop but the emulator is working fine

Answer (score 30, accepted):

My **Nexus 5X API 24 and 25** Emulators works well but **Nexus 5X API 26** and above are very slow, I check memory and CPU costs in **Android Profiler** it shows much higher than others, *even simulators have the same density*.

I think currently we often choose latest Emulators (**from API 26 - Android 8.0** and above) **ONLY** for testing code that relates to OS features changes, for stable and performance testing, we should choose Emulators ***equal or below*** **API 25 - Android 7.1**. 
I reported this problem to Google, hope they will make some enhancements soon.

Comment: Thanks! My emulator was so slow. Changed from 28 to 25.

Comment: Changed from Android 30 to 25 and the difference is epic! Now the OS splash screen takes 20 minutes to complete :D

Comment: @ThomasLAURENT 20 minutes is not necessarily fast tho :D

Answer (score 34):

Try this:

Go to the emulator settings and try to select different values for **OpenGL ES Renderer**:

[image]

Comment: I have a macbook, and Desktop Native OpenGL did the job for me.
Thanks

Comment: This option is now under emulator's `Settings` -> `Advanced` tab

Comment: From the options, Desktop native OpenGL worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: Holy moly - why isn't `Desktop native OpenGL` on by default?! Switching to it now made everything smooth as butter!

Comment: Wow ....Just wow. Runs super smooth now. (Macbook M1)

Comment: CPU i7-4th gen => `Desktop native OpenGL` _/

Answer (score 6):

The Android Emulator is very slow. The main reason is because it is emulating the ARM CPU & GPU, unlike the iOS Simulator, which runs x86 code instead of the ARM code that runs on the actual hardware.

And one more, Why should you not go for Genymotion. I have used as as option for Android Emulator. It is better than Android Emulator.

If you really want to speed up the process, I would like to help you with this.

Follow these steps, ,may be your problem come to an end.

- Use actual hardware devices
- Don’t Run the Emulator in a Virtual
  Machine

Comment: is Genymotion a free tool ? if yes please share the link to download, because  can't find a free one in the official website. thanks

Comment: Previously it is free for individual users but It is paid unfortunately. I am surprised to see that it is paid now. I recommend you use physical device by enabling developer mode and use vysor with it. By using vysor you mobile on your PC/Laptop. Here is link of vysor website. https://www.vysor.io/

Answer (score 2):

I use this configuration on MAC

[Configuration Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCNja.png)

- GPU Mode: Host
- Ram: 1024
- SDCard Size: 10M

Answer (score 1):

My Android Studio Emulator was very slow, but the PC was not the problem, I have 16 RAM, 512 SSD, Intel i7 11 gen.

My problem was the amount of RAM for the emulator that was given. The amount of given RAM was 1.5 GB RAM, so I changed that to 3 GB RAM and now the emulator is working smoothly, without lagging or getting stuck.

To change the amount of given RAM for your emulator follow these steps:

1. Open Android Studio
2. Select `Projects` and then click on `More Actions` then select the `Virtual Device Manager` from the dropdown menu

[image]

3. A new window will pop up and then click the edit icon on your emulator
   [image]
4. After that another window will pop up. You will need to click on the button where it says `Show Advanced Settings`, after that the window will expand and you should scroll down and see RAM input where you can set the amount of RAM for your emulator

[image]

5. Click `Finish` and you are done