# How to make Android emulator faster on M1 Mac with a React Native project?

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, android-emulator, qemu

I'm on an 64GB M1 Max, with an emulated Android device Pixel 3a which is arm64-v8a. Basically everything is ARM64. Android Studio 2022.3.1 (Giraffe) and macOS Ventura 13.5.

However, my React Native project runs extremely slow (which works 60FPS smooth on iOS simulator): Videos play super-sluggish, UI animations are at around 4-5 FPS, any transitions/button presses have around 2-sec lags etc. It's slow like the days that we used to emulate ARM64 on Intel devices.

Based on some other answers on this topic, I've already tried:

- Launching in tool window/wiping/restarting emulator
- Adding the lines `-Dsun.java2d.opengl=true` and `-Dsun.java2d.opengl.fbobject=false` to studio.vmoptions.

However they make absolutely zero difference.

How can I make Android emulator faster, at least to an acceptable level?

Comment: I haven't found a great way to do this - generally I do perf testing on a physical device.  The iOS simulator performance is deceptive, since it's using your CPU; if you're evaluating animations especially I'd always test on device.

Comment: @Abe sure, but I don't have access to a physical Android device. Also, even if I did, I need to test for various screen sizes/dimensions/pixel densities etc. anyway. I can't have all those devices physically.

Comment: Increase the amount of ram that your emulator uses. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52600963/why-android-studio-emulator-is-extremely-slow/77096908#77096908

Answer (score 0):

try to use this settings :

I think you can increase the value 2048 to 4096

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure anything except line 15 on that screenshot would affect runtime speed as they're about building/packaging configuration.

But I'll try increasing memory size.